# Tableau: Blending Datasets that have common metrics but not common dimensions

Tags: join, tableau-api, blending

Let's say that I have two datasets that share common Measures but not common Dimensions.

Dataset A:
NAME  |  SALES
A     |  1
A     |  2
A     |  3

Dataset B:
NAME  |  SALES
B     |  4
B     |  5
B     |  6

I'm trying to create a visualization that shows Total Sales for Name A & B in the same visualization: 
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxmPs.jpg)

Data blending requires all unique values of my common dimension (i.e., NAMES) to be present in one dataset.  I've attempted to create a dummy dataset to enable this blending, but it's not quite getting there

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Nat, what you need is not a blend, but a *UNION*. Imaging that A has 3 entries still, but B has a thousand: both your question and chart are still valid but there is no way to map A to B one-to-one.

You desired data would look like:

```
NAME | SALES
A    | 1
A    | 2
A    | 3
B    | 4
B    | 5
B    | 6
B    | 7
...
```

How to achieve this depends on where your data resides. If it's in a SQL database, in a different tables, you can use Custom SQL and `UNION ALL` in SQL code. If it's in external data files, such as Excel or CSV, you can also use custom SQL on a Windows machine if you open the data source with the "legacy connector". There is currently no support for custom SQL to text sources on a mac currently. In that case, you would need to prepare the data yourself.

In the future, it might be easier. Tableau team has showed some future features during the opening keynote of the 2015 Tableau Conference, available on their web site. One of the coming features demonstrates was support for UNION ALL.

Related discussion: http://community.tableau.com/ideas/3354

Comment: @Alex - thanks for your helpful edit. I'm on a Mac so didn't know about the legacy connection option.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Victor K.  I was hoping that wasn't the case!  My example only shows 2 data sources, but my real case has nearly 20 data sets. I guess manual union is the only way to go.